# Extract all emails from a file with \n delimiter

Tags: perl, extract

I have a file with results of a script as follows:

```
 22012784522fsdjtw5shaqq3w50ttj@fkhvenxh.net|FAIL|DNS failure: NXDOMAIN|net|fkhvenxh.net|22012784522fsdjtw5shaqq3w50ttj|22012784522fsdjtw5shaqq3w50ttj
20peterl@parishnational.com|FAIL|DNS timeout|com|parishnational.com|20peterl|20peterl
20amsaafd@snds.com|FAIL|DNS failure: NOERROR|com|snds.com|20amsaafd|20amsaaf
.342lhau@cmuvm.csv.cmich.edu|FAIL|DNS failure: NXDOMAIN|edu|cmuvm.csv.cmich.edu|342lhau|342lhau
2mf41nguolw@5cdu6on7wj.com|FAIL|DNS failure: NXDOMAIN|com|5cdu6on7wj.com|2mf41nguolw|2mf41nguolw
343qazu@cmuvm.bitnet|FAIL|DNS failure: NXDOMAIN|bitnet|cmuvm.bitnet|343qazu|343qazu
32ec69db3444001@mhbs.lsil.com|FAIL|DNS failure: NXDOMAIN|com|mhbs.lsil.com|32ec69db3444001|32ec69db3444001
2uon4eq@aneti.edu.pl|FAIL|DNS failure: NXDOMAIN|pl|aneti.edu.pl|2uon4eq|2uon4eq
 21juniora@attbi.com|FAIL|DNS failure: NOERROR|com|attbi.com|21juniora|21juniora
22sqrbean@midsouth.rr.com|FAIL|DNS failure: NXDOMAIN|com|midsouth.rr.com|22sqrbean|22sqrbean
```

I tried:

```
  perl -lne 'print $1 if /([^,@"]+@[^,@"]+)/' input > output
```

But it did not extract the emails or change anything in the file.

Please help me. Thank you!

Comment: How about a `split` on `|` and print the 0th field?

Comment: I read 'man split' and am unsure how to use split to do this.  I tried, split '[^|.*]' ALLEMAILS6.out.test > ALLEMAILS6.out.test.tmp, but this yielded, split: cannot open `[^|.*]' for reading: No such file or directory. Can you give me an example of what I should use?

Comment: You haven't told Perl to auto-split (`-a`) or what the field delimiter is (`-F '\|'`), and you'd need to access `$F[0]` even if you had done both those. To the extent it filters, your code will read anything up to the first `@`, the `@`, and anything except an `@` or `,` or `"` afterwards.  That means it prints the whole line on the example input. If that's what you see, it is working correctly according to the program you gave it. Maybe `perl -la -F'\|' -e 'print $1 if $F[0] =~ /^\s*([^,#"]+@[^@,"]+?)\s*$/'` is what you're after.  The `'\|'` is necessary; otherwise Perl splits each character.

Comment: Thank you @Jonathan Leffler

Comment: FYI, I tried this on a csv file and changed the '\|' to ',' and it did not put anything in the output file. Are there any other things I need to change? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In one line of Perl:

```
perl -lne "print /([^|]+)/" myfile
```

It works by printing the first sequence of non-pipe characters it find in each line of data

Comment: Thanks. I'm assuming that works with other delimiters by replacing the ^| with ^, or ^" for example, correct?

Comment: @technerdius: That's correct, yes. Although you would have to be careful to escape square brackets

Answer (score 0):

I forgot about the cut command:

Input:

```
 cut -d\| -f1 input > output
```

Output:

```
   22012784522fsdjtw5shaqq3w50ttj@fkhvenxh.net
   20peterl@parishnational.com
   20amsaafd@snds.com
   342lhau@cmuvm.csv.cmich.edu
   2mf41nguolw@5cdu6on7wj.com
   343qazu@cmuvm.bitnet
   32ec69db3444001@mhbs.lsil.com
   2uon4eq@aneti.edu.pl
   21juniora@attbi.com
   22sqrbean@midsouth.rr.com
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for a regex since you're dealing with a delimited format that makes things nice and simple.

```
while (<>) {
    my @fields = split(/\|/, $_);
    print "$fields[0]\n";
}
```